# Twitterizer - How to post a reply?

Tags: twitter, twitter-feed, twitterizer

I'm using the Twitterizer wrapper for a new ASP.NET project. I have a gridview showing me the twitter timeline. I have a button in every row to reply to a specific status message. But i just reply a message like this: "@screenName this is a reply". This is just a new statusupdate on my twitter. But the in_reply_to_user_id field of that status is not filled in.
What should i do to reply correctly to a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the `TwitterStatus.Update(...)` overloads accepts a `StatusUpdateOptions` parameter. This parameter allows you to specify the status that a tweet is in reply to with a `InReplyToStatusId` property.

For example, (I'm freehanding this code)

```
StatusUpdateOptions options = new StatusUpdateOptions();
options.InReplyToStatusId = 12345;
TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> replyResult = TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, "@somebody this is a reply", options);
```

Comment: Anytime you see an overload that accepts an options parameter that isn't `OptionalProperties` (that's the base type) that means there are extra options specific for that method. The base type will allow for the general stuff, like enabling use of SSL, proxy settings, and the built-in caching.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'll check it when i'm home. But i think your answer is just what i needed :) (i'll check then as accepted answer)

Comment: Hi,i try same code.It tweet it does not reply mentions

Comment: Your question is unclear: Does it return an error in the replyResult? Or does it post the status, but it's not a reply?